# Why is the base-class function not overridden?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, mfc, overriding

I override the base-class function `ShowProperties` in a sub-class, but still the base-class function gets called. Why is this?

**class hierarchy:**

```
class CDiagramEntity : public CObject
{
public:
  virtual void ShowProperties( CWnd* parent, BOOL show = TRUE );
}

class CNetworkSymbol : public CDiagramEntity
{
  /*NO 'ShowProperties' Function*/
}

class CDeviceEntity : public CNetworkSymbol
{
  /*NO 'ShowProperties' Function*/
}

class CSwitch : public CDeviceEntity
{
public:
  virtual void ShowProperties( CWnd* parent, BOOL show = TRUE );
}
```

Use:

```
/*Use Here*/
{
  CDiagramEntity* obj = GetSelectedObject();
  if( obj )
  {
    CSwitch* sw = (CSwitch*)obj;
     sw->ShowProperties( this );    
     /*calls CDiagramEntity's function, not CSwitch's function*/
  }
}
```

**PS:**

1. As @iammilind suggests, I removed virtual from CDiagramEntity and use casting, the function of CSwitch is called, and from the properties it shows(the properties can only be changed to what it shows when CSwitch is created), I am quite sure it is a CSwitch.
2. As @user1610015 comments, if I use

   ```
   CSwitch* sw = dynamic_cast<CSwitch*>(obj);
   ```

   it returns `NULL`.
3. As @Andrian Sham says, I got the problem's reason:

   ```
   GetSelectedObject()--->finally calls--->
   {
     CDiagramEntity* result = NULL;
     if ( index < m_objs.GetSize() && index >= 0 )
       result = static_cast< CDiagramEntity* >( m_objs.GetAt( index ) );
     /*m_objs is defined as: CObArray m_objs;*/
     return result;
   }
   ```

m_objs:

```
CObArray m_objs;
```

And the object is stored as:

```
...( CDiagramEntity* obj )
{
  obj->SetParent( this );
  m_objs.Add( obj );
  SetModified( TRUE );
}
```

But can someone explain this in more details?

Comment: First of all, you can change your whole `if` statement for `obj->ShowProperties(this);`? Second of all, how do you know that the parent's `ShowProperties()` is called?

Comment: It was called, really. I tried, still the same, I am using VC6.0. I debugged it.@Code-Guru

Comment: How do you know which ShowProperties() was called?

Comment: What type does GetSelectedObject() return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you do your debug.  You said you can see a member var of CSwitch.  If you mean you inspect `CSwitch* sw = (CSwitch*)obj;` and see such var in `sw`, you are in fact getting in wrong.  Debugger is simply "interpreting" the piece of memory pointed by `sw` as it is a CSwitch.  It doesn't mean that it is really a CSwitch.

I can only thought of a case.  Have you put the object instance in any STL container and get it out to put it as the select item?

(I forgot MFC totally, this is just an example)

```
vector<CDiagramEntity> entities;  // note it is of type CDiagramEntity, not CDiagramEntity*

CSwitch aCSwitch;
entities.push_back(aCSwitch);

// later
SetItem("SomeValue", entities[i]);
```

You may think you entities[i] should return an instance of CSwitch but it is not.

(This is the best I can guess if you are pretty sure that the selected item should be a CSwitch)

Comment: Yeah, got it! amazing guess! I ude CObArray to store the objects.

Comment: But it is CObArray of CDiagramEntity*, see what I edited for more details.

Comment: If you are storing pointers then it should be fine.  Can you check at the place you call the setup method? (the place passing in the CDiagramEntity* to add to m_objs)  Make sure that you haven't accidentally create a new CDiagramEntity instance

Answer (score 1):

Because the `ShowProperties()` is a **`virtual`** function.

When `virtual` mechanism kicks in, the function binding happens at **runtime**.
If `ShowProperties()` is returning an object of `class CDiagramEntity`, then `CDiagramEntity::ShowProperties()` will be called irrespective of `static type` of type calling pointer (here `sw`).

Just for experiment purpose, remove the `virtual` keyword and run the code. You will get the expected behavior. But beware of possible undefined behavior.

Comment: @Rubby, have you tried removing `virtual` keyword from both the functions, especially in `CDiagramEntity`?

Comment: Yes, if I removed virtual  in CDiagramEntity, it works.  But it is not what I want, I donot want to use casting actually.  It is only for testing or debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Because even if you cast a CDiagramEntity object to a CSwitch object, the call is made throgh virtual dispatch. So, if the object returned by GetSelectedObject is not actually a CSwitch, CDiagramEntity's ShowProperties is called.

Why are you casting the object to CSwitch? It doesn't make sense from a design perspective. You have a polymorphic object, and yet you want to treat it as one of its specialized derivations.

Comment: It is a CSwitch, I debugged it, and the sw has distinctive member of CSwitch.

Comment: Can you offer a convicable way to check its type?

Comment: The debugger should tell you. Or you can use a dynamic_cast instead of a parenthesis cast. dynamic_cast checks the runtime type at runtime and returns the object if it's actually of the requested type, otherwise it returns null.

Comment: You mean it's null after using dynamic_cast? Well, because as I said dynamic_cast returns null it the object's runtime type is not the requested type. That means it must be a CNetworkSymbol, a CDeviceEntity, or just a CDiagramEntity.